# How to extend airbnb eslint but with warnings instead of errors?

Tags: webpack, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I'm using airbnb's eslint with webpack like this:

`.eslintrc`:

```
{
  "extends": "airbnb"
}
```

---

`webpack.config.js`:

```
...
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      use: ['babel-loader', 'eslint-loader'],
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
    },
    ...
  ]
}
...
```

This works, but all the eslint rules show up as errors, eg:

```
1:28   error  Missing semicolon                             semi
2:45   error  Missing semicolon                             semi
5:7    error  Unexpected space before function parentheses  space-before-function-paren
```

How can I set it up so that all the rules from airbnb's eslint are warnings instead of errors?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Approach #1** adjust specific rules in `.eslintrc`:

```
{
  "extends": "airbnb"
  "rules": {
    "camelcase": "warn",
    ...
  }
}
```

see [Configuring Rules](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuring-rules)

**Approach #2** adjust `eslint-loader` to emit warnings instead of errors for all rules:

```
{
  ...
  loader: "eslint-loader",
  options: {
    emitWarning: true,
  }
}
```

see [Errors and Warning](https://github.com/MoOx/eslint-loader#errors-and-warning)

Comment: hmm I don't know why but adding `emitWarning: true` doesn't work, it still shows errors...

Comment: but webpack updates is no longer skipped because of `eslint-loader`? what is the problem then?

Answer (score -1):

To make the [Oles Savluk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3772379/oles-savluk)'s second solution work you may need to use **failOnWarning** flag:

```
{
    loader: 'eslint-loader',
    options: {
        emitWarning: true,
        failOnWarning: false,
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to have it only treat the airbnb rules as warnings, so that our other eslint rules can still be treated as errors?